# C++ Function that calls CALLBACK from different thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, callback

I've got the following structure:

***async.h***

```
class async{

public:
    static int run(void * aArgs);
    static int pro(void * aArgs);

    struct params{
        LPCTSTR aFile;
        LPCTSTR aTarget;
    };

    typedef DWORD (WINAPI *LPPROGRESS_ROUTINE)(
        LARGE_INTEGER TotalFileSize,
        LARGE_INTEGER TotalBytesTransferred,
        LARGE_INTEGER StreamSize,
        LARGE_INTEGER StreamBytesTransferred,
        DWORD         dwStreamNumber,
        DWORD         dwCallbackReason,
        HANDLE        hSourceFile,
        HANDLE        hDestinationFile,
        LPVOID        lpData
    );
```

};

***async.cpp***

```
DWORD CALLBACK MyCopyProgressRoutine(LARGE_INTEGER fileSize, LARGE_INTEGER bytesTransferred, LARGE_INTEGER StreamSize, LARGE_INTEGER streamBytestransferred, DWORD dwStreamNumber,  DWORD dwCallbackReason, HANDLE hSourceFile,  HANDLE hDestinationFile, LPVOID lpData){

...
... 
    return  PROGRESS_CONTINUE;
}

int async::pro(void * aArgs){

    CopyFileEx(file, target, &MyCopyProgressRoutine, NULL, NULL, COPY_FILE_FAIL_IF_EXISTS);

    return 0;
}
```

Then I call `async::pro` being executed in a different thread:

```
thrd_create(&t, jmmvAsync::pro, (void*)mParams);
```

Everything works fine. The problem comes when `CopyFileEx` function calls the defined function as CALLBACK. They are in a different thread so it produces a runtime error. How can I fix this so `CopyFileEx` can call its CALLBACK?

Answer (score 0):

in CopyFileEx the parameter after MyCopyProgressRoutine is a void * to some data for the progress routine (MyCopyProgressRoutine in your code). You can call CopyFileEx and pass it two different instances of the data you use to show progress.
To sum up: you would have the same CALLBACK but it will act on different data.